# Downloading a portion of a video using youtube_dl

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to download a portion of the video (say about 30 sec) using the `if` and `elif` statement and implement this on the below-given code. Currently, only my first and second option is working but I don't know how to apply the third option.

Currently, my implementation is:

```
import youtube_dl

def switch_demo(x):

    switcher = {

                1: "With Subtitles", 
                2: "Without Subtitles",
                3: "Download short video(take 30 sec)", 
    }


    return switcher.get(x,"Invalid Option")

x = int(input("Select the option\n1.With Subtitles\n2.Without Subtitles\n3.Download short video(take 30 sec)\n\n"))

print(switch_demo(x))

link=input('Please enter a url link\n')


if (x == 1):

    ydl_opts = {"writesubtitles": True}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:

        ydl.download([link])

elif ( x == 2):

    ydl_opt = {}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opt) as ydl:

        ydl.download([link])

elif (x == 3):

    ffmpeg (youtube-dl -g ([link)] | sed "s/.*/-ss 10 -i &/") -t 60 -c copy test3.mkv
```

I tried with a command line utility like ffmpeg but its not working and I don't know how to apply this in the above code.

I would like to able to download the video with or without the subtitles or only a portion of video(upto 30 sec) with all the options working.

Comment: You need to use `os.system()` or subprocess to call an external command.

Comment: can you please explain how can i do that@PrinceOfCreation

Comment: `os.system("<PUT YOUR COMMAND IN HERE>")`

Comment: I tried but it is not working                                                            
 os.system("ffmpeg ([link)] | sed 's/.*/-ss 10 -i &/') -t 60 -c copy test3.mkv")